# Java error "missing return statment"

Tags: java, return-value

So here's my code:

```
public class Bob {

    public static int F(int n) {
        if (n > 1) {
            if (n % 2 == 0) {
                n = n / 2;
                System.out.println(n);
                return F(n);
            } else if (n % 2 != 0) {
                n = 3 * n + 1;
                System.out.println(n);
                return F(n);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Complete");
                return 0;
            }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = F(10);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find where the error is. All the possible values of n are covered. If I add a simple return value outside of the if-statment, it will work, but I don't see why that should be the case.

Also, I'd like to add a print "i" statement into main, but whenever I do something like:

```
if (something){
   int i;
   i++;
   do something
```

I try to add a System.out.println(i) and it gives me an error about a static variable.

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket.

Comment: What are you returning if `n` is 0?

Comment: @Andreas The code won't even get that far.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I can't find an open bracket. Maybe it's because I'm just using a simple text editor, but everything looks closed to me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Don't understand you comment. "Missing brace" and "missing return" are both compiler errors, so code don't go anywhere in either case.

Comment: @Astrum You're missing `}` after `return 0;`. Your indentations are good, so it's easy to spot. Recommend you use an IDE, not a text editor.

Comment: I suspect that the missing `}` should be before the last `else`, not after `return 0`.

Comment: I also suspect that the `}` is there in the original code and got dropped out when posting the question.  I don't believe Java will even get to the phase where it displays "missing return" if it hits a bad syntax error like mismatched braces first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code makes no sense, as posted.  You have an `if/else` statement with three branches.  The first branch is executed if `n%2` is 0.  The second branch is executed if `n%2` is not zero.  Since that covers all the possibilities, when is the third branch supposed to be executed?

Because this doesn't make sense (and because I've seen this coding problem before), I suspect that you meant the third branch to be executed if the first `if` is false, i.e. if `n <= 1`.  But because of the curly braces, the compiler attaches the "else" to the `if (n%2...)` branches, not to `if (n > 1)`.  To fix this, you need another curly brace:

```
public static int F(int n){
    if (n > 1){             // ***** Opening brace 1
        if (n%2 == 0){
            n = n/2;
            System.out.println(n);
            return F(n);
        } else if(n%2 != 0){  // ***** Opening brace 2
            n = 3*n+1;
            System.out.println(n);
            return F(n);
        }            // This curly brace matches "opening brace 2"
    }                // This curly brace matches "opening brace 1"
    else {
        System.out.println("Complete");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

But that still isn't legal, and the reason isn't obvious.  What happens here is that Java requires that you have a `return` statement in every possible path.  And here's what the compiler thinks: If `n > 1`, then you have an `if` statement `if (n%2 == 0)`.  If this fails, it goes to the `if` statement `if (n%2 != 0)`.  If this is also false, then it will drop down past the last `else` part, and it will get to the end of the method without returning anything.

Of course, you and I will look at it and say, that's impossible, because either `n%2 == 0` or `n%2 != 0` must be true.  But that requires that we do some reasoning.  Java compilers don't do that kind of reasoning, so it can't tell that one of those two `if` expressions must be true.

So fixing this also requires that you change

```
        } else if(n%2 != 0) {
```

to

```
        } else {
```

You don't need the `if` anyway--it's totally redundant.  If we get here, we already know that `n%2 != 0`.

Answer (score 2):

> Question 1

You have to add the `return;` statement in method cause it may never enter `if` statement.The compiler doesn't know with what variables you will call the method so :

**return something;**

Also you miss a bracket here

```
else{ System.out.println("Complete"); return 0;}
```

If instead you want to use the final else as the return point then your method has to be like this:

```
public static int F(int n) {
        if (n > 1) {
            if (n % 2 == 0) {
                n = n / 2;
                System.out.println(n);
                return F(n);
            } else if (n % 2 != 0) {
                n = 3 * n + 1;
                System.out.println(n);
                return F(n);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Complete");
            return 0;
        }
}
```

> Question 2

Using non static variables into static methods is not allowed if they are out of method scope.That is cause static methods are loaded faster that simple methods and variables which are non static may have not been initialized yet.

What i mean:(not allowed)

```
 int b;
 public static void main (String[ ] args){ 

  // variable ( b)  has to be static to be used here   

 }
```

Comment: Oh I see, I missed that. Is there anyway to get the method to return just the print statement, or is there o other way than placing a dummy output of 0?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int F(int n) {
        if (n > 1) {
            if (n % 2 == 0) {
                n = n / 2;
                System.out.println(n);
                return F(n);
            } else if (n % 2 != 0) {
                n = 3 * n + 1;
                System.out.println(n);
                return F(n);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Complete");
                return 0;
            }
    }
```

The error **missing return statement** is because you are not specify return statement if n is less than 1.. So, what this fucntion return  if the provided **parameter** **n** is less than 1 like 0. You should specify it in else statement or even with single return statement like **return -1** on the last line of function;